# Deploy AngularJS app into docker container

Tags: angularjs, node.js, docker

I am trying to deploy my angularjs app into a docker container:

**myapp/web/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /myapp
ADD . /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

RUN npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt
RUN npm install -g bower

RUN npm install
RUN bower install --allow-root
RUN npm run v2

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["grunt", "serve"]
```

**myapp/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  web:
    build: ./web
    image: myapp/web
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.dev
```

**Outputs**

```
> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

Considering PhantomJS found at /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Looks like an `npm install -g`
Could not link global install, skipping...
Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Receiving...

Received 22866K total.
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1497270232242/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /usr/ local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Phantom installation failed { Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-149727 0232242/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'link',
  path: '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1497270232242/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64',
  dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom' } Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs- 2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1497270232242/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/ph antom'
npm info lifecycle phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14~install: Failed to exec install script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-12T12_23_56_471Z-debug.log
```

I tried to add `USER root` before the global npm install but nothing changes.

Any help apreciated

Comment: run with sudo user

Comment: tried and I get the same result

Comment: sudo npm install

Comment: sudo command not found

Comment: @kitensei - could you share detailed logs at `/root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-12T12_23_56_471Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to get the logs from that container, the npm errors stops the container directly and `docker [imagename] logs` returns nothing...

Comment: I have encountered the same problems, and do you have any solutions ?

Comment: I think you need to wait for the release of npm v5.0.4, or you can use the npm 4 version

Comment: My solution (which is not really one) is to remove my windows host and install ubuntu, works great now :S

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and this works for me.

`sudo npm install -g phantomjs@2.1.1 --unsafe-perm`

https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/707#issuecomment-320989493